# Requiring OpenGL ES 2 in Android App

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-manifest

Just to be sure, when requiring ES2 in Android app, you just need to append  `android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"` to any uses-feature tag?

Should this actually be its own uses-feature tag? Are there any issues with this being combined as an attribute in another uses-feature tags that requires a particular hardware?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Developer's Guide has [a section on this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#manifest):

```
<!-- Tell the system this app requires OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

I would say that the above code should be fine.

Comment: Agreed, I would have it as a separate element, to be on the safe side, rather than trying to combine it with one using `android:name`. It's not *that* many more characters, and you are insulated from any tools that might assume they should be in separate elements.